# Is there a way to see "local SERP" traffic in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, local-seo, google-my-business

Is there a way to see "local SERP" traffic in Google Analytics?

Eg. data generated from the Google My Business (GMB) profile on the google SERP page.

I'm aware that I can see some simple reporting in the GMB dashboard, but is there a way I can get this natively integrated into Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2):

You can use UTM parameters in the URLs you enter into your GMB listing.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863
https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/campaign-url-builder/

The values you enter will override GA's source/medium and campaign values. I set the source/medium to google/organic to indicate Google Search and set the campaign to something that identifies the listing. e.g. "GMB-12345". You can then identify GMB visits via the campaign.